# S3 presigned urls are expiring too early

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The url is signed for 6 hours. The `X-Amz-Date` and `X-Amz-Expires` add upto the correct time. However, the url itself starts giving `Access Denied` errors several minutes before expiry time.

We're using `aws-sdk-s3` for ruby, fwiw, in a kubernetes environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the our pods were using InstanceProfileCredentials. These are temporary, rotated credentials, which are also used to sign the urls we generate. So, if the current credential token is expiring in 4 hours, then the url will also be live for max 4 hours, even if we set a higher expiration time for url.

A bit of code to get the expiration of current token:

```rb
resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
  region: 'us-east-1'
)
expiration = resource.client.config.credentials.expiration
# "2021-05-03T11:49:47.569+00:00"
```

This returns an instance of `Time` class. Based on this, we were able to calculate the max expiry we can set for a url and avoid 4xx errors.